# Angular form error if two fields dont match

Tags: javascript, forms, angularjs

Is there a way to make a form invalid if two inputs don't match (like passwords), in Angular? Similar to  `form.password.$error.required`?

Answer (score 5):

```
 pwd1:<input type="password" ng-model="pwd1" required /><br />
 pwd2:<input type="password" ng-model="pwd" required /><br />

      <div ng-show="pwd1 && pwd">Invalid:
        <span ng-show="pwd1!==pwd">Wrong</span>
        <span ng-show="pwd1===pwd">Correct</span>
      </div>
```

This just checks if both the passwords are same.
[Angular Form validation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms)

Also check this [Angular Ui](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-utils/)  which has password match directive

Comment: I saw many solutions with ng-directive but this is simpler. I wonder if there any flaw on this because til now it works fine for me.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Angular UI, it has a `ui-validate` directive:

```
<input name="password" required ng-model="password">
<input name="confirm_password" ui-validate=" '$value==password' " ui-validate-watch=" 'password' ">
```

Or, you can build your own directive for that

```
myApp.directive('matchPassword', function () {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            matchPassword: '='
        },
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
            scope.$watch(function () {
                return (ctrl.$pristine && angular.isUndefined(ctrl.$modelValue)) || scope.matchSenha === ctrl.$modelValue;
            }, function (currentValue) {
                ctrl.$setValidity('matchPassword', currentValue);
            });
        }
    };
});
```

and use it like so:

```
<input required name="passwordConfirm" match-password="model.Password" />
```